# Migration from DB2 to PostgreSQL-TO_CHAR()

Tags: postgresql-9.2

While migrating my application from DB2 to PostgreSQL.

I want to migrate the following functions in PostgreSQL.

`TO_CHAR()` in DB2 which can take three arguments as follows:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(CURRENT_DATE,'YYYY-MM-DD',112.50) FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
```

I am not sure what is the purpose of the third argument in `TO_CHAR()` function of DB2.

I think we can create one user define function with name `TO_CHAR` which can take three arguments like DB2.

I want to know that if we want to create user define function `TO_CHAR()`.

What should be the data type of the third argument?

which can handle maximum data types and more suitable for real time scenarios.

Comment: I find nothing in the DB2 documentation about that third parameter.

Comment: Are you sure your to_char is not a UDF?

Comment: Third argument is used to set locale in DB2.

Comment: Some times third argument is used to format the string passed to the function.